# Get type of a std::variant member at a given index during compile time

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I have defined the following variant:

```
std::variant<int, bool, MyType, int> myVar;
```

The type of the member at index `2` is `MyType`. How to get this during compile time? (so that I can use it in a `constexpr` context etc..)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`std::variant_alternative`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant_alternative)

> Provides compile-time indexed access to the types of the alternatives
> of the possibly cv-qualified variant, combining cv-qualifications of
> the variant (if any) with the cv-qualifications of the alternative.

```
using T = std::variant_alternative_t<2, decltype(myVar)>;
```

Answer (score 8):

Since C++17, you can use [std::variant_alternative_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant_alternative)

```
std::variant_alternative_t<0, std::variant<int, std::string>> i; // int
std::variant_alternative_t<1, std::variant<int, std::string>> s; // string
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Shouldn't we swap the template typenames. i.e. index goes first ?

Comment: @Sumudu yup. fixed