# Does the standard or some Boost library offer a compile-time variant?

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, variant, compile-time

I'm not asking how to [Get type of a std::variant member at a given index during compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63122084/get-type-of-a-stdvariant-member-at-a-given-index-during-compile-time).

I'm asking whether the standard or some boost library offer a `std::variant`-like class whose contained type is known at compile time.

What I'm asking, I believe, is not completely nonsense, as there's [`boost::hana::optional`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1optional.html) which plays the same role (as the type I'm imagining), but with respect to [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

As regards its utility, it would allow one to write several overloads into one, e.g.

```cpp
void f(std::string, A);
void f(std::string, B);
void f(int, A);
void f(int, B);
```

could be written as

```cpp
void f(var<std::string, int>, var<A, B>);
```

Clearly the implementation would make use of `if constexpr` to branch on the input types.

Comment: If it's going to be the same type, why use a variant? Why not use a template?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain how this compile-time variant would be different than a template?  If you want to limit it to certain types, that would be most easily implemented as a C++20 _concept_.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [C++ templates that accept only certain types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874298/c-templates-that-accept-only-certain-types)

Comment: `var<std::string, int>` could probably be turned into a concept where it is only resolved if the type passed to the function is one of the type specified in the `<>`.

Comment: @DrewDormann, you're right, it's not different, except that... isn't a concept expressing "is either concrete type A or concrete type B" a bit overkill?

Answer (score 3):

Building on the comments and Spencer's answer, C++20 concepts and abbreviated template functions will give you almost exactly what you described.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template <class T, class... Ts>
concept var = (std::is_same_v<T, Ts> || ...);

struct A{};
struct B{};

void f(var<int, std::string> auto a1, var<A, B> auto a2) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(a1), int>) {
        // int path
    } else {
        // string path
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/G5WdMTdGP

Answer (score 1):

You can already accomplish your stated goal with a function template.  Any type of variant would complicate things unnecessarily.  You would have a traits type somewhere in a header:

```
// one_of.h
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class First, class...Rest>
struct one_of
{
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<First>, First>);
   static constexpr bool value = std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, First> 
                               || one_of<T, Rest...>::value;
};


template <class T, class First>
struct one_of<T, First>
{
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<First>, First>);
   static constexpr bool value = std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, First>;
};


template <class T, class...Cands>
constexpr bool one_of_v = one_of<T, Cands...>::value;
```

And then, in your actual program code, you would use the `one_of_v` template to restrict (via a c++20 function constraint) the types allowed as parameters:

```
#include "one_of.h"
#include <string>

struct A{};
struct B{};

template <class A1, class A2>
requires one_of_v<A1, std::string, int> && one_of_v<A2, A, B>
void f(A1 && a1, A2 && a2)
{
   if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int, A1>)
   {
       // do int stuff
   }
   else
   {
      // guaranteed to be string, do string stuff
   }
}

int main()
{
    int d;
    A e;
    f(d, e); // matches
    std::string s;
    B b;
    f(s, b); // matches
    //double a;
    //double b;
    //f(a, b); // no match
}
```

Now, `one_of` is a bit ham-handed and I would probably use more subtle traits types in real code, but this demonstrates the concept correctly.

I've personally found `if constexpr` with type traits very useful in reducing the number of overloads needed for template functions.  Plus, it explains all the different cases more succinctly, all right next to each other, than overloaded functions that may be spread out in a way that you can't comprehend all at once.